# Selecting values within a range

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find the number of rows which contain a value greater than 7 and less than 13.99.
However, the following query always returns 0, and that's just not possible.

Can anyone see a problem in my query?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lead_status AS ls 
INNER JOIN leads AS l ON l.id = ls.lead_id 
INNER JOIN contacts AS c ON c.lead_id = l.id 
WHERE ls.discriminator = 'AUTO_POST' AND l.affiliate_id=1003 
AND ls.winner =1 AND l.test =0 AND l.create_date BETWEEN '2011-10-03' AND '2011-10-17' 
AND ls.amount >= 7 AND ls.amount <= 13.99;
```

Comment: Why is that "just not possible"? I no record is found according to your condition, count(*) will be zero

Comment: And why is not possible?, are you completely certain of it?, remember that you have other filters

Comment: Yes, I'm completely certain that there can not be 0.

Comment: How are you doing that count, then?, excel?. Can you show us some test data?, cause your query looks fine to me

Comment: Does your query return non-zero if you eliminate the tests on ls.amount?

Comment: The table definitions and some sample data might help to help.

Comment: Maybe its not your where clause, but your JOIN criteria. Try changing them to LEFT joins, and do a select *, then you can easily see whether the JOIN criteria is wrong, or whether its due to the WHERE clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor edit, some formatting and a suspicion:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   lead_status ls 
INNER  JOIN leads l ON l.id = ls.lead_id    -- ls.id .. l.lead_id ??
INNER  JOIN contacts c ON c.lead_id = l.id 
WHERE  ls.discriminator = 'AUTO_POST'
AND    ls.winner = 1
AND    ls.amount >= 7
AND    ls.amount <  14
AND    l.affiliate_id = 1003 
AND    l.test = 0
AND    l.create_date BETWEEN '2011-10-03' AND '2011-10-17';
```

You have `ls.lead_id` and `c.lead_id`, but `l.id`. That seems inconsistent. Typo?

You write:

> greater than 7 and less than 13.99

Your code says:

> greater than or equal to 7 and less than or equal to 13.99

I changed it to (I suspect that's what you really want):

> greater than or equal to 7 and less than 14

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems fine. But just to be sure first remove all filters on the query and then add them one by one you will get which filter is causing the count to be zero.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post your schema but it is possible that you need to cast your string dates to actual date values:

```
...AND l.create_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2011-10-03', '%Y-%M-%d') AND 
                             STR_TO_DATE('2011-10-17', '%Y-%M-%d')
```

Comment: this isnt necessary when dates are passed in UTC format (ie, YYYY-MM-DD). Of course it might be that his create_date field is not a true date time to begin with